# Fibonacci LFSR - polynomial , sequence, phase shift

Tags: flipflop, shift-register, register

[image]

Hi, it's my first post here. I have a question according this picture. So let's see.

IMHO the primitive polynomial for that LFSR will be \$x^4+x+1\$ but I'm not sure if I'm thinking good. I've read somewhere that flip-flops are \$x^0
\$, \$x^1\$, \$x^2\$, \$x^3\$, \$x^4\$ starting from the input and we consider only these that are connected with XOR gate. Here I don't know which flip-flop is \$x^0\$ and which is \$x^4\$?

Starting from `1000` we will have `1000 -> 0100 -> 1010 -> 0101 -> 0010 -> 0001 -> 1000` so bits of \$m_1\$ will be `0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1` yup?

And the part with \$m_1\$ delayed by 4 clock cycles. It's probably easy one but I don't have any ideas what's going on.

Comment: Oh, come on. At least try Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register

Comment: ok i think that i understand how to write this polynomial but what with this phase shifter?

Comment: Let's say you added another flip-flop after M1. What would the output look like? How about 2 flip-flops in series? Do you see a pattern?

Comment: i think phase shifter means adding some extra xor gate and connecting it with appropriate Q

Comment: No. Read the question again. It doesn't say any such thing. It specifies a delay of 4 clock cycles. Clock cycles - does that suggest anything? Like flip-flops?